# How to install the Word addIn, without the vsto file or the setup.exe

Tags: c#, ms-word, installation, vsto, word-addins

I want to install my Word addIn on another PC. I know I can run the vsto file to install the addIn or I can use the setup.exe, but that's not what I want. I want to manually install the addIn. That means, I must know where to put my assemblies and how I connect them to word.

Comment: That's basically not possible. A lot more has to happen than just copying the assemblies somewhere. Things need to be written to the Registry, for example and security/trust needs to be established. The only way would be to run the VSTO project from within Visual Studio in debug mode. If you want an add-in that can simply be copied to another machine then it needs to be VBA in a Word file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. You have to write only five things into the registry:
[image]

This can be done with a small script. The Value "Wert nicht festgelegt" means "No Value"

The Location in the registry is `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\AssemblyName`

The security values will be written automatically in the registry `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTO\Security\Inclusion`